# Is there a way to display the drop down spinner list on page loads in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to display the list of my array in the spinner when the page first loads and also when the user touches on the spinner.

I am doing this :

```
String[] simpleArray = {"java","android","Data Structures","HTML","CSS"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> usageListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_small_text, simpleArray);
        usageListAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        btn_list_type.setAdapter(usageListAdapter);
        btn_list_type.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        btn_list_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                listTypePickerSelected(pos);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Try using `btn_list_type.performClick()` as an aritifcial click event.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu this doesn't work either.. It crashes my app.

Comment: You should add the error stack trace of the crash in the question.

Comment: @EraftYps if I do btn_list_type.performClick() then it gives this error: Unable to add window — token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: It means you called `performClick()` too early. Move `performClick()` method invocation into `onResume`, just to test that there will be no exception. No exceptions should appear from `onResume`.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu same issue from onResume as well.

Comment: Please, post full code of your Activity below the snippet you have shown.